# How to export file at specific location in angularjs or javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, download, export-to-csv

I am working in angularJs. i used fileSaver.js for export the file. exported file stored in download folder. but i want to export or download selected file to desktop loacation.
So how i achieve this?
is there any other solution with or without filesaver.
is there a way to achieve this solution in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can’t.

Long answer: Again, you can’t.

I am not sure what you are trying to do here but I am assuming you are writing a script which will enable a browser user to click on one link and get a number of files downloaded, and that too to a local directory. If that were possible, that would represent a great security risk.

The only way to do that is to configure your google chrome to download to a specific folder. Javascript doesn't have access your local disk.

Comment: So it means we can't set download location using programatically?

Comment: Hey Chiran, they could be some ways of creating a window service, and opening a session channel using javascript, but it would need the user to install the service, am not sure if it is worth it.even popular websites and system don't provide such a feature because it not supported out of the box.